# Can a point have an attitude?

Tags: geometry

So I was sitting and reading the various takes on visualising the 4th dimension in this [popular question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286180/visualizing-the-4th-dimension).  And I was thinking of how people are simply struggling.  They are often trying to use drawings and the use of eyes to visualise it and I thought that might not be the best way to look at it.

So I thought, hey, why not try visualising it with touch and your ears.  Several thought experiments later, and I thought of some real world examples, especially in quantum physics.

So I have to ask before I take things too far with these thought experiments: **can a point have an attitude?**

Wikipedia article on [Attitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_(geometry))

Comment: How are you defining "attitude" here?

Comment: touch and ears are as equally bound to the 3-d physical constraints as eyes so for as I can tell.  Still worth pursuing.  What the heck is an attitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question. Yes. in a sense this concept is known as a [tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field). This is where each point in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ is assigned a value or a vector. Does that answer your question? Sometimes the assigned values can even be complex (i.e. $\mathbb C^n$).